# OPC-UA certificate issues

Tags: qt, security, openssl, ssl-certificate, opc-ua

I'm using Qt `qtopcuaviewer` [example](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtopcua/qtopcua-opcuaviewer-example.html) to test the connection to a PLC.
Usually it works fine and I can retrieve the variables. With this specific PLC I get the following output:

```
"Creating PKI path '/home/user/bin/pki/trusted/certs': SUCCESS."
"Creating PKI path '/home/user/bin/pki/trusted/crl': SUCCESS."
"Creating PKI path '/home/user/bin/pki/issuers/certs': SUCCESS."
"Creating PKI path '/home/user/bin/pki/issuers/crl': SUCCESS."
Discovering servers on  "opc.tcp://192.168.1.50:4840"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.userland: "AcceptAll Certificate Verification. Any remote certificate will be accepted."
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.securechannel: "Connection 11 | SecureChannel 3778283009 | Opened SecureChannel with SecurityPolicy http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#None"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "Client Status: ChannelState: Open, SessionState: Closed, ConnectStatus: Good"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "Client Status: ChannelState: Closed, SessionState: Closed, ConnectStatus: Good"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.userland: "AcceptAll Certificate Verification. Any remote certificate will be accepted."
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.securechannel: "Connection 11 | SecureChannel 3778283010 | Opened SecureChannel with SecurityPolicy http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#None"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "Client Status: ChannelState: Open, SessionState: Closed, ConnectStatus: Good"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "Client Status: ChannelState: Closed, SessionState: Closed, ConnectStatus: Good"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541: Directory is empty
Client state changed QOpcUaClient::Connecting
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541: Directory is empty
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.userland: "AcceptAll Certificate Verification. Any remote certificate will be accepted."
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.securitypolicy: "The Basic128Rsa15 security policy with openssl is added."
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.securitypolicy: "The basic256 security policy with openssl is added."
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.securitypolicy: "The basic256sha256 security policy with openssl is added."
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "The configured ApplicationURI does not match the URI specified in the certificate for the SecurityPolicy http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#None"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.securechannel: "Connection 11 | SecureChannel 3778283011 | Opened SecureChannel with SecurityPolicy http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#None"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "Client Status: ChannelState: Open, SessionState: Closed, ConnectStatus: Good"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "Rejecting UserTokenPolicy 0 (username) in endpoint 0: configuration doesn't match"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "Rejecting endpoint 1: security mode doesn't match"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "Rejecting endpoint 2: security policy doesn't match"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "Rejecting endpoint 3: security mode doesn't match"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "Rejecting endpoint 4: security policy doesn't match"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "Rejecting endpoint 5: security mode doesn't match"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "No suitable UserTokenPolicy found for the possible endpoints"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541.sdk.client: "Client Status: ChannelState: Closed, SessionState: Closed, ConnectStatus: BadInternalError"
qt.opcua.plugins.open62541: Open62541: Failed to connect
Client error changed QOpcUaClient::UnknownError
Client state changed QOpcUaClient::Disconnected
```

The PLC's developer says there are no certificates required - still I'm not sure to understand the root cause of the refused connection.

Is anything I can do to debug this issue? Or it's so clear and my limited knowledge is preventing me to fix it?

### EDIT

In the `getEndpoints()` function I added the following debug calls:

```
void MainWindow::getEndpoints()
{
    ui->endpoints->clear();
    updateUiState();

    if (ui->servers->currentIndex() >= 0) {
        const QString serverUrl = ui->servers->currentText();
        createClient();
        mOpcUaClient->requestEndpoints(serverUrl);
        qDebug() << mOpcUaClient->supportedSecurityPolicies();
        qDebug() << mOpcUaClient->supportedUserTokenTypes();
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
QList("http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#None", "http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#Basic128Rsa15", "http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#Basic256", "http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#Basic256Sha256")

QList(0, 1)
```

Here the enumeration for `TokenType`:

```
enum TokenType {
    Anonymous = 0,
    Username = 1,
    Certificate = 2,
    IssuedToken = 3
};
Q_ENUMS(TokenType)
```

May this help?

### UPDATE

With the application mentioned above I find these endpoints:

[image]

From my understanding it appears as a request of certificates.
Instead, other machines (the ones that work) show this other endpoint:

[image]

So, is it true that the first machine "does not require any security certificate" as stated by the manufacturer?

Comment: I guess the PLC Does not provide any matching Security Policies or UserTokenTypes with your Client... You can use supportedSecurityPolicies() and supportedUserTokenTypes() to check what your Client support. Wireshark packet capture might help as well

Comment: @CamilleG. question updated. Please let me know if I can do anything else to find out how to fix the issue.

Comment: @CamilleG. question updated with the discovered endpoints

Answer (score 1):

192.168.1.50 seems to only support Secure communication (None is not present). 192.168.1.12 support only Unsecure communication. I guess your OPC UA Client is not configured to connect to a Secure Server. Check with another OPC UA Client supporting Secure communication ( ie: UA Expert)